# Kinesis python client drops any message with "\x" escape?

Tags: python, python-2.7, protocol-buffers, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I'm using boto3 (version 1.4.4) to talk to Amazon's Kinesis API:

```
import boto3
kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')

# write a record with data '\x08' to the test stream
response = kinesis.put_record(StreamName='test', Data=b'\x08', PartitionKey='foobar')
print(response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']) # 200

# now read from the test stream
shard_it = kinesis.get_shard_iterator(StreamName="test", ShardId='shardId-000000000000', ShardIteratorType="LATEST")["ShardIterator"]
response = kinesis.get_records(ShardIterator=shard_it, Limit=10)
print(response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']) # 200
print(response['Records']) # []
```

When I test it with any data without the `\x` escape I'm able to get back the record as expected. [Amazon boto3's doc](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#Kinesis.Client.put_record) says that "The data blob can be any type of data; for example, a segment from a log file, geographic/location data, website clickstream data, and so on." then why is the message with `\x` escaped characters dropped? Am I expected to `'\x08'.encode('string_escape')` before sending the data to kinesis?

If you are interested, I have characters like `\x08` in the message data because I'm trying to write a serialized protocol buffer message to a Kinesis stream.

Comment: Are you saying that your Lambda function never receives the message with the binary data in it?

Comment: @garnaat I'm not using any lambda function, I was just using a python kinesis client to read from the stream after I wrote to it. I'm saying that despite the message write appeared to be successful, when I read from the stream there was no record regardless of how long I wait after the write. Though I was able to read the record after writing a message without the `\x` escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured it out. The reason why it wasn't working was because my botocore was on version `1.4.62`. I only realized it because another script that ran fine on my colleague's machine was throwing exceptions on mine. We had the same boto3 version but different botocore versions. After I `pip install botocore==1.5.26` both the other script and my kinesis `put_record` started working.

tldr: `botocore 1.4.62` is horribly broken in many ways so upgrade NOW. I can't believe how much of my life is wasted by outdated broken libraries. I wonder if Amazon dev can unpublish broken versions of the client?